# Verifiying answers from application to web service and vice versa

Tags: algorithm, web-services, security, verification

Scenario:

My Application stands in connection to Web service (Master Server). Sometimes i make calls like **login on application startup**, where my application sents user credentials to the master server for validating.

So, how do i **1st** validate that the answer is from my **real** server and not a fake local webserver with routed hosts file? And **2nd** how do i parse this answer?

I always parsed like this (dummy code):

```
if($answerFromWebserver == "LOGIN_OK") {
    doLogin();
}
```

Are there better, more safe solutions?

Answer (score 1):

some of the security feature I see/use,

1. You can allow specific IPs to server, can setup firewall for this.
2. Setting up SSL/HTTPS will be great benefit to secure transport level.
3. You can send username/password encrypted with every message, so at server side authentication will took place each time. You can use SOAP header for this.

You can read huge article from ms [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648643.aspx) on securing services..